# Redis: Return all values stored in a database

Tags: python, redis

We're using Redis to store various application configurations in a DB 0.

Is it possible to query Redis for every key/valuie pair within the database, without having to perform two separate queries and joining the key/value pairs yourself?

I would expect functionality similar to the following:

```
kv = redis_conn.getall()
# --OR-- #
kv = redis_conn.mget('*')
```

... Where `kv` would return a tuple of tuples, list of lists, or a dictionary:

However after scouring StackOverflow, Google and Redis documentation, the only solution I can derive (I haven't yet found anyone else asking this question..) is something similar to the following:

```
import redis
red = redis.Redis(host='localhost', db=0)
keys = red.keys()
vals = red.mget(keys)
kv = zip(keys, vals)
```

Am I crazy here, in assuming there to be a more elegant approach to this problem?

### Additional Info

Every value within this database is a String.

My question is not how to retrieve values for each unique data type or data-type related at all.

Rather, my question is: Is there a way to say `"hey Redis, return to me every string value in the database"` without having to ask for the keys, then query for the values based on the keys returned?

Comment: Just for strings, or you want to query all data types? `MGET` returns `nil` for anything that's not a string.

Comment: All values are currently stored as strings, so just strings are fine.

Comment: If you need it for debugging purposes, you might want to check out the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079165/52499).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are differences between different types in Redis, so you have to look at the data type to determine how to get the values from the key. So:

```
keys = redis.keys('*')
for key in keys:
    type = redis.type(key)
    if type == "string":
        val = redis.get(key)
    if type == "hash":
        vals = redis.hgetall(key)
    if type == "zset":
        vals = redis.zrange(key, 0, -1)
    if type == "list":
        vals = redis.lrange(key, 0, -1)
    if type == "set":
        vals = redis. smembers(key)
```

Comment: Where do the `KV`, `HASH` and `ZSET` come from? I do not see them if I do `dir(redis)`.

Comment: @ideawu, it would be worth answering the anove mention comment - Because I'm at a loss as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that if it is saved in binary like `b'string'` you will have to check the type against the string in binary. Example: `if type == b'string'`

Comment: @MatteoGuarnerio you can decode the values by default. So something like `r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost', 6379, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)`. Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44032018/3480297