# How to get all keys with their values in redis

Tags: redis

I know that in order to get all the list of all keys in Redis, I have to use `KEYS *`, but is there a way to output all keys together with their values?

Few minutes of searching did not yield any result.

P.S. thank you very much for answers, but I am looking for a native solution. I can write a function that iterates through all the output of `KEYS *` by myself.

Comment: It does seem that after 4 years of no solution, the answer might be "no"

Comment: Check out an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079165/52499) from a similar question.

Answer (score 65):

#### There is no native way of doing this.

The [Redis command documentation](http://redis.io/commands) contains no native commands for getting the key and value of multiple keys.

The most native way of doing this would be to load a [lua script](http://www.lua.org/start.html) into your redis using the [`SCRIPT LOAD`](http://redis.io/commands/script-load) command or the [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL) command.

## Bash Haxx solution

A **workaround** would be to use some bash magic, like this:

```
echo 'keys YOURKEY*' | redis-cli | sed 's/^/get /' | redis-cli
```

This will output the data from all the keys which begin with YOURKEY

Note that the keys command is a blocking operation and should be used with care.

Comment: It only works for string values, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312607/52499).

Answer (score 50):

Yes, you can do print all keys using below bash script,

```
for key in $(redis-cli -p 6379 keys \*);
  do echo "Key : '$key'" 
     redis-cli -p 6379 GET $key;
done
```

where, 6379 is a port on which redis is running.

Comment: Thanks! This is the most straight forward approach

Comment: Assuming you got jq installed, you can get a pretty print for json values by piping it `redis-cli GET $key | jq .`.

Answer (score 24):

I refined the **bash** solution a bit, so that the more efficient *scan* is used instead of *keys*, and printing out array and hash values is supported. My solution also prints out the key name.

*redis_print.sh*:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Default to '*' key pattern, meaning all redis keys in the namespace
REDIS_KEY_PATTERN="${REDIS_KEY_PATTERN:-*}"
for key in $(redis-cli --scan --pattern "$REDIS_KEY_PATTERN")
do
    type=$(redis-cli type $key)
    if [ $type = "list" ]
    then
        printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli lrange $key 0 -1 | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
    elif [ $type = "hash" ]
    then
        printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli hgetall $key | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
    else
        printf "$key => $(redis-cli get $key)\n"
    fi
done
```

Note: you can formulate a one-liner of this script by removing the first line of *redis_print.sh* and commanding: `cat redis_print.sh | tr '\n' ';' | awk '$1=$1'`

Comment: This bash command should be running on the same server as the redis instance?

Comment: You could modify the script to connect a remote instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678950/1097104

Answer (score 14):

KEYS command should not be used on Redis production instances if you have a lot of keys, since it may block the Redis event loop for several seconds.

I would generate a dump (bgsave), and then use the following Python package to parse it and extract the data:

https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

You can have json output, or customize your own output in Python.

Comment: +1 One may not realize how important this is! If you're storing the keys in a consistent manner, you should be able to retrieve them without needing the keys command.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! I noticed that `bgsave` doesn't store the keys which contains only digits as its keyName; Also to parse the redis _dump.rdb_ files you can use `strings` command too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget) to get the values of multiple keys in a single go.

Example:

```
redis> SET key1 "Hello"
"OK"
redis> SET key2 "World"
"OK"
redis> MGET key1 key2 nonexisting
1) "Hello"
2) "World"
3) (nil)
```

For listing out all keys & values you'll probably have to use bash or something similar, but `MGET` can help in listing all the values when you know which keys to look for beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I felt on your post.

I think the easiest way to solve this issue is by using redis Hashtable.

It allows you to save a Hash, with different fields and values associated with every field.

To get all the fiels and values `client.HGETALLL` does the trick. It returns an array of

all the fields followed by their values.

More informations here https://redis.io/commands/hgetall

Answer (score 3):

Use this script for redis >=5:

```
#!/bin/bash
redis-cli keys "*" > keys.txt
cat keys.txt | awk '{ printf "type %s\n", $1 }' | redis-cli > types.txt
paste -d'|' keys.txt types.txt | awk -F\| '
   $2 == "string"               { printf "echo \"KEY %s %s\"\nget %s\n", $1, $2, $1 }
   $2 == "list" || $2 == "set"  { printf "echo \"KEY %s %s\"\nsort %s by nosort\n", $1, $2, $1 }
   $2 == "hash"                 { printf "echo \"KEY %s %s\"\nhgetall %s\n", $1, $2, $1 }
   $2 == "zset"                 { printf "echo \"KEY %s %s\"\nzrange %s 0 -1 withscores\n", $1, $2,$1 }
' | redis-cli
rm keys.txt
rm types.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is just a little variant of the script provided by @"Juuso Ohtonen".

I have add a **password variable** and **counter** so you can can check the progression of your backup. Also I replaced simple brackets `[]` by **double brackets** `[[]]` to prevent an error I had on macos.

### 1. Get the total number of keys

```
$ sudo redis-cli
INFO keyspace
AUTH yourpassword
INFO keyspace
```

### 2. Edit the script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Default to '*' key pattern, meaning all redis keys in the namespace
REDIS_KEY_PATTERN="${REDIS_KEY_PATTERN:-*}"
PASS="yourpassword"
i=1
for key in $(redis-cli -a "$PASS" --scan --pattern "$REDIS_KEY_PATTERN")
do
    echo $i.
    ((i=i+1))
    type=$(redis-cli -a "$PASS" type $key)
    if [[ $type = "list" ]]
    then
        printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli -a "$PASS" lrange $key 0 -1 | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
    elif [[ $type = "hash" ]]
    then
        printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli -a "$PASS" hgetall $key | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
    else
        printf "$key => $(redis-cli -a "$PASS" get $key)\n"
    fi
    echo
done
```

### 3. Execute the script

```
bash redis_print.sh > redis.bak
```

### 4. Check progression

```
tail redis.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small code for this particular requirement using hiredis , please find the code with a working example at http://rachitjain1.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-get-all-keyvalue-in-redis-db.html

Here is the code that I have written,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hiredis.h"

int main(void)
{
        unsigned int i,j=0;char **str1;
        redisContext *c; char *t;
        redisReply *reply, *rep;

        struct timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 }; // 1.5 seconds
        c = redisConnectWithTimeout((char*)"127.0.0.2", 6903, timeout);
        if (c->err) {
                printf("Connection error: %s\n", c->errstr);
                exit(1);
        }

        reply = redisCommand(c,"keys *");
        printf("KEY\t\tVALUE\n");
        printf("------------------------\n");
        while ( reply->element[j]->str != NULL)
        {
                rep = redisCommand(c,"GET  %s", reply->element[j]->str);
                if (strstr(rep->str,"ERR Operation against a key holding"))
                {
                        printf("%s\t\t%s\n",  reply->element[j]->str,rep->str);
                        break;
                }
                printf("%s\t\t%s\n",  reply->element[j]->str,rep->str);
                j++;
                freeReplyObject(rep);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried the given example, but over VPN and with 400k+ keys it was too slow for me. Also it did not give me the key objects.

I wrote a small Python called tool [redis-mass-get](https://pypi.org/project/redis-mass-get/) to combine `KEYS` and `MGET` requests against Redis:

```sh
# installation:
pip install redis-mass-get

# pipeline example CSV:
redis-mass-get -f csv -och redis://my.redis.url product:* | less

# write to json-file example with progress indicator:
redis-mass-get -d results.json -jd redis://my.redis.url product:*
```

It supports JSON, CSV and TXT output to file or `stdout` for usage in pipes. More info can be found at: [Reading multiple key/values from Redis](https://keestalkstech.com/2020/08/reading-multiple-key-values-from-redis/#introducing-redis-mass-get-cli).

Answer (score 1):

This shell script retrieves all Redis keys with their corresponding values using the SCAN command.

It uses a while loop to iterate through batches of keys retrieved from Redis, and a for loop to iterate through the keys in each batch. For each key, it retrieves its value using the GET command, and prints the key-value pairs in a formatted manner to the console.

The script continues to retrieve and process batches of keys until all keys have been retrieved

```bash
    #!/bin/sh
    
    # Start Redis CLI and retrieve all keys using SCAN command
    redis_keys=$(redis-cli --raw SCAN 0)
    
    # Loop through keys and retrieve values
    while [ "$redis_keys" != "0" ]; do
      # Extract the cursor and keys from SCAN command response
      cursor=$(echo "$redis_keys" | head -n 1)
      keys=$(echo "$redis_keys" | tail -n +2)
    
      # Loop through the keys and retrieve their values
      for key in $keys; do
        value=$(redis-cli --raw GET "$key")
        echo "Key: $key | Value: $value"
      done
    
      # Retrieve the next batch of keys using the new cursor
      redis_keys=$(redis-cli --raw SCAN "$cursor")
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

With `redis-cli` you can export keys and values as following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get all keys and their values using redis-cli
redis-cli --raw KEYS "*" | while read key; do
  value=$(redis-cli --raw GET "$key")
  echo "$key: $value" >> "redis_dump.txt"
done
```

Every key and value will be added as a new line in redis_dump.txt.

Answer (score 0):

> scan 0 MATCH * COUNT 1000  // it gets all the keys 
>         if return is "0" as first element then count is less than 1000
>         if more then it will return the pointer as first element and >scan pointer_val MATCH * COUNT 1000 
>         to get the next set of keys it continues till the first value is "0".

Comment: This doesn't suggest why to use scan vs. keys (which wasn't the question to begin with); and doesn't explain how to get the values for those keys.

Answer (score 0):

This simple script worked for me (I store in my REDIS key-value sets)

```
#!/bin/bash

for key in $(redis-cli -p <port> -n <db num> keys \*);
  do
    OUTPUT=$(redis-cli -p <port> -n <db num> GET $key)
    echo "$key", "${OUTPUT}" >> redis_pairs.csv
done
```

You simply execute it:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh
```

The final output is a .csv file (comma delimiter) of the pairs I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the script with some more keys and here goes

```
#!/bin/bash

# Default to '*' key pattern, meaning all redis keys in the namespace
REDIS_KEY_PATTERN="${REDIS_KEY_PATTERN:-*}"
for key in $(redis-cli --scan --pattern "$REDIS_KEY_PATTERN")
do
    type=$(redis-cli type $key)
    if [ $type = "list" ]
    then
        printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli lrange $key 0 -1 | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
    elif [ $type = "hash" ]
    then
        printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli hgetall $key | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
    elif [ $type = "smembers" ]
    then
        printf "$key => $(redis-cli smembers $key)\n"
    elif [ $type = "zset" ]
    then
        printf "$key => $(redis-cli zrange $key 0 -1)\n"
    elif [ $type = "set" ]
    then
        printf "$key => $(redis-cli smembers $key)\n"
    else
        printf "$key => $(redis-cli get $key)\n"

    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out solution for Alpine linux container

- Create file `redis`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  apk --update add redis
  host="$1"
  port="$2"

  redis-cli -h "${host}" -p "${port}" --scan --pattern 'key_prefix_*' | while read key;
  do
     value=$(redis-cli -h "${host}" -p "${port}" get "${key}")
     echo "${key} : ${value}"
  done
  ```
- Run: `chmod 755 redis`
- Run: `/bin/sh redis {Your Redis Host} {Your Redis Port}`

Answer (score 0):

Same output as firelync one-liner, but easier to type and only invokes redis twice:

```
echo 'keys YOURKEY*' | redis-cli | xargs  redis-cli mget
```

Only suitable for a hand full of values, and ommits the name of the key

Answer (score -2):

check out my tool, [rdd](https://github.com/r043v/rdd)

```
rdd -v
```

will output you all keys with data

Comment: +1, Also with `-m` option, we can print only keys which matches given pattern.

Comment: this did not work? need to install something additional? (my redis is running on RHEL 7.3)

Comment: redis-cli lib is the only dependency
please be more explicit in your bug report ..
maybe your keys got binary names ?
filter request to try not use the full set, to isolate faultly keys

Comment: You may want to mention it is your own project.