# Redis semaphore locks can't be released

Tags: ruby, redis, mutex, semaphore

I am using the [redis-semaphore gem](https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore), version `0.3.1`.

For some reason, I occasionally can't release a stale Redis lock. From my analysis it seems to happen if my Docker process crashed after the lock was created.

I have described my debugging process below and would like to know if anyone can suggest how to further debug.

Assume that we want to create a redis lock with this name:

```rb
name = "test"
```

We insert this variable in two different terminal windows. In the first, we run:

```rb
def lock_for_15_secs(name)
  job = Redis::Semaphore.new(name.to_sym, redis: NonBlockingRedis.new(), custom_blpop: true, :stale_client_timeout => 15)
  if job.lock(-1) == "0"
    puts "Locked and starting"
    sleep(15)
    puts "Now it's stale, try to release in another process"
    sleep(15)
    puts "Now trying to unlock"
    unlock = job.unlock
    puts unlock == false ? "Wuhuu, already unlocked" : "Hm, should have been unlocked by another process, but wasn't"
  end
end
lock_for_15_secs(name)
```

In the second we run:

```rb
def release_and_lock(name)
  job     = Redis::Semaphore.new(name.to_sym, redis: NonBlockingRedis.new(), custom_blpop: true, :stale_client_timeout => 15)
  release = job.release_stale_locks!
  count   = job.available_count
  puts "Release reponse is #{release.inspect} and available count is #{count}"
  if job.lock(-1) == "0"
    puts "Wuhuu, we can lock it"
    job.unlock
  else
    puts "Hmm, we can't lock it"
  end
end
release_and_lock(name)
```

This usually plays out as expected. For 15 seconds, the second terminal can't relase the lock, but when run after 15 seconds, it releases. Below is the output from `release_and_lock(name)`.

Before 15 seconds have passed:

```
irb(main):1:0> release_and_lock(name)
Release reponse is {"0"=>"1580292557.321834"} and available count is 0
Hmm, we can't lock it
=> nil
```

After 15 seconds have passed:

```
irb(main):2:0> release_and_lock(name)
Release reponse is {"0"=>"1580292557.321834"} and available count is 1
Wuhuu, we can lock it
=> 1
irb(main):3:0> release_and_lock(name)
Release reponse is {} and available count is 1
Wuhuu, we can lock it
```

But whenever I see that a stale lock isn't released, and I run `release_and_lock(name)` to diagnose, this is returned:

```
irb(main):4:0> release_and_lock(name)
Release reponse is {} and available count is 0
Hmm, we can't lock it
```

And at this point my only option is to flush redis:

```rb
require 'non_blocking_redis'
non_blocking_redis = NonBlockingRedis.new()
non_blocking_redis.flushall
```

P.s. My `NonBlockingRedis` inherits from `Redis`:

```rb
class Redis
  class Semaphore
    def initialize(name, opts = {})
      @custom_opts          = opts
      @name                 = name
      @resource_count       = opts.delete(:resources) || 1
      @stale_client_timeout = opts.delete(:stale_client_timeout)
      @redis                = opts.delete(:redis) || Redis.new(opts)
      @use_local_time       = opts.delete(:use_local_time)
      @custom_blpop         = opts.delete(:custom_blpop) # false=queue, true=cancel
      @tokens               = []
    end

    def lock(timeout = 0)
      exists_or_create!
      release_stale_locks! if check_staleness?
      token_pair    = @redis.blpop(available_key, timeout, @custom_blpop)
      return false if token_pair.nil?
      current_token = token_pair[1]
      @tokens.push(current_token)
      @redis.hset(grabbed_key, current_token, current_time.to_f)
      if block_given?
        begin
          yield current_token
        ensure
          signal(current_token)
        end
      end
      current_token
    end
    alias_method :wait, :lock
  end
end

class NonBlockingRedis < Redis

  def initialize(options = {})
    if options.empty?
      options = {
        url: Rails.application.secrets.redis_url,
        db:  Rails.application.secrets.redis_sidekiq_db,
        driver: :hiredis,
        network_timeout: 5
      }
    end

    super(options)
  end

  def blpop(key, timeout, custom_blpop)
    if custom_blpop
      if timeout == -1
        result = lpop(key)
        return result if result.nil?
        return [key, result]
      else
        super(key, timeout)
      end
    else
       super
    end
  end

  def lock(timeout = 0)
    exists_or_create!
    release_stale_locks! if check_staleness?
    token_pair = @redis.blpop(available_key, timeout, @custom_blpop)
    return false if token_pair.nil?
    current_token = token_pair[1]
    @tokens.push(current_token)
    @redis.hset(grabbed_key, current_token, current_time.to_f)
    if block_given?
      begin
        yield current_token
      ensure
        signal(current_token)
      end
    end
    current_token
  end
  alias_method :wait, :lock
end

require 'non_blocking_redis'
```

Comment: Well, almost 2 years later, im facing the same problem, did you use bliof PR? did it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An awesome bug

## The bug

I think it happens if you kill the process when it does lpop on the `SEMAPHORE:test:AVAILABLE`

Most probably here https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore/blob/v0.3.1/lib/redis/semaphore.rb#L67

To replicate it

```
NonBlockingRedis.new.flushall

release_and_lock('test');

NonBlockingRedis.new.lpop('SEMAPHORE:test:AVAILABLE')
```

Now initially you have:

```
SEMAPHORE:test:AVAILABLE                0
SEMAPHORE:test:VERSION          1
SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS           1
```

After the above code you get:

```
SEMAPHORE:test:VERSION          1
SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS           1
```

The code checks the `SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS` and then expects to have `SEMAPHORE:test:AVAILABLE` / `SEMAPHORE:test:GRABBED`

## Solution

From my brief check I don't think it is possible to make the gem work without a modification. I tried adding an `expiration:` but somehow it managed to disable the expiration for `SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS`

```
NonBlockingRedis.new.ttl('SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS') # => -1 and it should have been e.g. 20 seconds and going down
```

So.. maybe a fix will be

```
class Redis
  class Semaphore
    def exists_or_create!
      token = @redis.getset(exists_key, EXISTS_TOKEN)

      if token.nil? || all_tokens.empty?
        create!
      else
        # Previous versions of redis-semaphore did not set `version_key`.
        # Make sure it's set now, so we can use it in future versions.

        if token == API_VERSION && @redis.get(version_key).nil?
          @redis.set(version_key, API_VERSION)
        end

        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the all_tokens is https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore/blob/v0.3.1/lib/redis/semaphore.rb#L120

I'll open a PR to the gem shortly -> https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore/pull/66 maybe ‍♂️

## Note 1

Not sure how you use the `NonBlockingRedis` but it is not in use in `Redis::Semaphore`. You do `lock(-1)` which does in the code `lpop`. Also the code never calls your `lock`.

## Random

Here is a helper to dump the keys

```
class Test
  def self.all
    r = NonBlockingRedis.new
    puts r.keys('*').map { |k|
      [
        k,
        ((r.hgetall(k) rescue r.get(k)) rescue r.lrange(k, 0, -1).join(' | '))
      ].join("\t\t")
    }
  end
end

> Test.all

SEMAPHORE:test:AVAILABLE                0
SEMAPHORE:test:VERSION          1
SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS           1
```

For completeness here is how it looks when you have grabbed the lock

```
SEMAPHORE:test:VERSION          1
SEMAPHORE:test:EXISTS           1
SEMAPHORE:test:GRABBED          {"0"=>"1583672948.7168388"}
```

Comment: What an amazing effort @bliof. Thanks a lot. I will try out your solution first thing tomorrow. A quick note: `Test.all` returns `Redis::CommandError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` in my end. About your `Note 1`: I realise that I left out my existing `Redis > Semaphore` overrides. I have added them to my question.

Comment: That error is because there is some other type of data in your redis. You get every type with a custom call e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078018/get-keys-and-values-at-command-prompt 

Just ignore it ‍♂️ `rescue nil` or try all of them. As far as I can tell the bug still hold with the additional code.  hf

Comment: Hm, seems I am having troubles a Docker process crash, so I am not yet sure if it works. However, so far all stale locks have been unlocked with the overwrite. I will go ahead and check off the answer before the bounty expires, but I hope you would be so kind to give it a look if I submit additional comments later on.